# how to escape a single quote in a pig script

Tags: apache-pig

Can pig scripts use double quotes?  If not how to escape a single quote?  I'm trying to parse a date time and I'm geting errors

```
Unexpected character '"'
```

And here is the script

```
logOutput = FOREACH parsedLog GENERATE uid, ToDate(timestamp,"YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm ss:'00'") as theTime:datetime
```

Comment: Pig does not accept double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try escaping them using `\` and using single quotes.

```
logOutput = FOREACH parsedLog GENERATE uid, ToDate(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD\'T\'hh:mm ss:00') as theTime:datetime
```

Not sure what you mean with `'00'`.

Comment: Works for me. Did you use single quotes or double quotes? Which version of pig are you using?

Comment: Ok, works now, I had to change the end of it to ss:ss ... not sure if that's the right way to do it but works since all our times end in 00:00

Answer (score 4):

You can escape a single quote using `\\` (double backslash).

```
%declare CURRENT_TIME_ISO_FORMAT ToString($CURRENT_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')
```

Just be aware that when you are using the escaping, you should not reuse the created String on another place of the script, but to everything on single call.
For example, let's say you want to send the String to the [ISOToDay](https://github.com/simplegeo/hadoop-pig/blob/master/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/truncate/ISOToDay.java) function, this script will fail:

```
%declare CURRENT_TIME_ISO_FORMAT ToString($CURRENT_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')
%declare TODAY_BEGINNING_OF_DAY_ISO_FORMAT ISOToDay($CURRENT_TIME_ISO_FORMAT)
```

Instead, you should do:

```
%declare TODAY_BEGINNING_OF_DAY_ISO_FORMAT ISOToDay(ToString($CURRENT_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'))
```